# KineticJS Node.create from JSON object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've been trying to load a layer (gave up trying with a layer and started trying with the stage) that I saved as a JSON object literal with the KineticJS .toJSON() method. I've been debugging my script and everything seems to be fine until the Kinetic.Node.create is called. Here's my code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 650
  });
var check;
$(document).on({
click: function(){

    check = stage.toJSON();

}
},'#save');

$(document).on({
click: function(){
    try{
       //parse check string into object literal
       var s = JSON.parse(check);
       //check if s is object literal
       if( Object.prototype.toString.call(s) === '[object Object]' ) {

            //this is where the code stops executing
            stage = Kinetic.Node.create(s,'container');
            stage.draw();
       }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.debug(e.stack);
        console.trace();
    }
}
},'#load');
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
<div id="buttons">
<button id="save">
    Save
</button> 
<button id="load">
    Load
</button>
</div>
```

And the error log:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
at Object.parse (native)
at Function.Kinetic.Node.create (http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js:2:25166)
at HTMLButtonElement.$.on.click (http://localhost/mosaicos/main.js:181:38)
at HTMLDocument.b.event.dispatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:28337)
at HTMLDocument.v.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:25042)
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your `.create()` call, you're passing in `'container'` as a string, but in the documentation for Kinetic.Node.create, it says that it should be a DOM element, not a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't think that's the issue since I've tried loading other objects, like a layer, without the optional DOMElement container and it sends the same error. Plus I checked the example on http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/ and it is using the same syntax.

Comment: It says in the documentation "optional container dom element used only if you're creating a stage node", so it may be required for a stage, but not layers/other objects.

Comment: I'm still using the exact same syntax used in the canvas load example, and I get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `Kinetic.Node.create` you need to pass the same string that you saved (`check`) and not the parsedJSON string (`s`)
So your command should essentially look like this:

```
var newNode = Kinetic.Node.create(stage.toJSON());
```

replace stage.toJSON with the variable where you saved that string.

This should give you the correct idea. Alternately, just open the developer tools and put a breakpoint after the save. Copy the value of the variable that now contains stage as a JSON string and then run `Kinetic.Node.create` in *console* with the copied string as the argument.